# Windows Server killing long running PHP process

Tags: php, windows, command-line

I have a Windows 2012 Server that runs IIS and SQL Server 2012.

I am trying to run a PHP script from the command prompt. The script takes around 1 hour to run. If I run it straight from the command line like this - c:\PHP>php.exe "D:\Web\phpScript.php" it runs fine. Again it takes around 1 hour to run but it completes fine.

The thing is I need to run it from another PHP page. So this code - exec('start c:\php\php.exe "D:\Web\phpScript.php"'); in PHP runs the script. When I run it from PHP like that it runs good for around 30 minutes or so but for some reason Windows ends up killing the process after around 30 minutes.

I have been watching the task manager on Windows and cannot see any difference in the way the process runs compared to when I run it straight from the command prompt or when I use PHP to run the command. They both show up as a background process and look exactly the same in the task manager but for some reason Windows is killing the one that runs from PHP and not the one ran straight from the command prompt.

I have even tried running the PHP one in Realtime thinking maybe if it had higher priority it would not get killed but that did not help.

I am really stuck with this.

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Use process explorer instead of task manager. it will also show you the parent process which invoked the binary. If it runs inside the parents process space the parent might notice and kill after 30 minutes whereas when you run it from CLI windows won't care.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It's running under the original php-cgi.exe that fired it off. So it seems like PHP is killing it. I've played with the time_limit on the PHP page but I don't think that is coming into play here. Any other ideas how to get PHP to stop killing it?

Comment: It might be a setting of your webserver. Which webserver are you using? Which Server-API?

Comment: Unfortunately it's IIS 8. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Check the documentation of the IIS 8 which limits are set for spawning CGI processes. I can imagine that the webserver pro-actively kills long running CGI spawns. Check the windows event log as well.

Comment: Thanks, I found some settings for CGI timeouts. I adjusted them and I am testing now. Thanks again.

Comment: That was it. There are some settings for fast cgi in IIS. I increased the timeout and it works good now. Thanks again. Do you want to move this to a full answer so I can award the answer?

Comment: I suggest as you actually know the exact settings you've done that you document those in an answer your own. That will keep you a log for the future. I was just guessing in comments which did help you in the end, but that has more to do with getting some feedback from somebody else then technical experience per-se. You now got the technical experience, so it's better you write the answer.

Comment: @Sequenzia, can you specify what's the configuration did you do in order to get it working? My scripts as simple as it can be as a set_time_limit(0); while(true) { sleep(600); } closes after 1 hour +/-. I tried some configuration on IIS but not working...

Answer (score 0):

If it has to do with your PHP configuration, you can force allowing a certain execution time with this at the beginning of the script

`set_time_limit(60*60*2); // allows 2 hours execution time`

Then to execute the external file just use `include('D:\Web\phpScript.php');` in the script.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Otherwise if its a server problem, beats me. You could, of course...run it in your web browser instead of in the command prompt, if PHP is installed on the machine.